# Raphael Elements Overlap on Zoom with controls

Tags: svg, zooming, raphael

I am running into an issue where where my Zoom+ button does zoom the elements but they overlap    as the elements grow.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/knottAverage/ArKDp/28/

Here is the function I am using for zoom+

```
$maxIcon.click(function(e) {
mapZoom /= mapMultiplier;
rsrGroupies.scale(mapZoom);
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
rsr.setViewBox(0, 0, rsr.mapWidth, rsr.mapHeight);
});​
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Mass-scaling the set is doing exactly what it's supposed to -- it's scaling every element.  It would take additional logic to translate each element relative to a center point as well.

But I believe the viewbox could be used to accomplish exactly the same effect.  [This variation of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/Hg5RX/3/) demonstrates how to adjust the view area of the canvas in response to zoom, and adds drag-and-drop to support navigation to hidden areas of the zoomed venue map.  Sadly, it is also horrendously broken -- indeed, just functional enough to point out a possible solution vector.  I hope you'll find it helpful instead of infuriating!

The trickiest thing may be that the zoom button (and any other navigation components) will need to be translated and scaled to *negate* the manipulation of the viewable area.  Otherwise, they'll zoom and shift along with the rest of the canvas!  It might be advisable to create a second paper over the top of the first (using absolute positioning and an appropriate z-index) and place your navigation elements in the topmost layer.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help and good thought on the nav elements. I am creating the nav elements just to render in ie7 and 8. My original version of this works but is very sluggish in ie7 and 8, so I thought reverting to control element for ie's would be a better experience. If you have any suggestions I would love to hear it and once again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add zoom buttons as separate PNG images (via jQuery) on top of SVG container to make them independent from SVG so they don't zoom-in-out with viewBox change (that's what I did with my SVG map).

Comment: Oh no, it was the individual shapes that were over lapping, not the actual buttons.

I was able to fix the overlap of shapes though, using setViewBox, then with creating different canvas size dimension as "var"s I was able to pull off a pretty nifty zoom feature and using jquery ui was able to get a draggable going. With those combined the thing was pretty fast even in ie6.